# Python Readline Loop and Subloop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, readline

I'm trying to loop through some unstructured text data in python. End goal is to structure it in a dataframe. For now I'm just trying to get the relevant data in an array and understand the line, readline() functionality in python.

This is what the text looks like:

```
Title: title of an article
Full text: unfortunately the full text of each article,
is on numerous lines. Each article has a differing number 
of lines. In this example, there are three..
Subject: Python
Title: title of another article
Full text: again unfortunately the full text of each article,
is on numerous lines.
Subject: Python
```

This same format is repeated for lots of text articles in the same file. So far I've figured out how to pull out lines that include certain text. For example, I can loop through it and put all of the article titles in a list like this:

```
a = "Title:"
titleList = []
sample = 'sample.txt'
with open(sample,encoding="utf8") as unstr:  
for line in unstr:
      if a in line:
        titleList.append(line)
```

Now I want to do the below:

```
a = "Title:"
b = "Full text:"
d = "Subject:"
list = []
sample = 'sample.txt'
with open(sample,encoding="utf8") as unstr:  
for line in unstr:
  if a in line:
    list.append(line)
  if b in line:
     1. Concatenate this line with each line after it, until i reach the line that includes "Subject:". Ignore the "Subject:" line, stop the "Full text:" subloop, add the concatenated full text to the list array.<br>
     2. Continue the for loop within which all of this sits
```

As a Python beginner, I'm spinning my wheels searching google on this topic. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with your for-loop, you're probably going to need something like this:

```
titles = []
texts = []
subjects = []

with open('sample.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    inside_fulltext = False
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Title:"):
            inside_fulltext = False
            titles.append(line)
        elif line.startswith("Full text:"):
            inside_fulltext = True
            full_text = line
        elif line.startswith("Subject:"):
            inside_fulltext = False
            texts.append(full_text)
            subjects.append(line)
        elif inside_fulltext:
            full_text += line
        else:
            # Possibly throw a format error here?
            pass
```

(A couple of things: Python is weird about names, and when you write `list = []`, you're actually overwriting the label for the `list` class, which can cause you problems later. You should really treat `list`, `set`, and so on like keywords - even thought Python technically doesn't - just to save yourself the headache. Also, the `startswith` method is a little more precise here, given your description of the data.)

Alternatively, you could wrap the file object in an iterator (`i = iter(f)`, and then `next(i)`), but that's going to cause some headaches with catching `StopIteration` exceptions - but it would let you use a more classic while-loop for the whole thing. For myself, I would stick with the state-machine approach above, and just make it sufficiently robust to deal with all your reasonably expected edge-cases.

Answer (score 1):

As your goal is to construct a DataFrame, here is a `re`+`numpy`+`pandas` solution:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read all file
with open('sample.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    text = f.read()


keys = ['Subject', 'Title', 'Full text']

regex = '(?:^|\n)(%s): ' % '|'.join(keys)

# split text on keys
chunks = re.split(regex, text)[1:]
# reshape flat list of records to group key/value and infos on the same article
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(e) for e in np.array(chunks).reshape(-1, len(keys), 2)])
```

Output:

```
                      Title                                                                                                                                               Full text Subject
0       title of an article  unfortunately the full text of each article,\nis on numerous lines. Each article has a differing number \nof lines. In this example, there are three..  Python
1  title of another article                                                                               again unfortunately the full text of each article,\nis on numerous lines.  Python
```